# Changing the location of .sparkStaging directory

Tags: apache-spark

For all my applications, spark creates its working directory under `<myPath>/.sparkStaging` on `HDFS`. Is it possible to tell spark to create this staging directory at different location for each application?

I explored the [Configurations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) and closest relevant I found was `spark.local.dir` but I dont think that will solve the purpose. Any suggestions?